# CCLayer Subclass randomly crashes when adding CCSprite

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, cocos2d-iphone

For some reason, whenever I call my CCLayer subclass within a block that is being executed else where the code seems to crash with EXE_BAD_ACCESS.

```
[[DataModel sharedInstance] saveWithSuccess:^{
                CCAlertView *alertView = [[CCAlertView alloc] initWithMessage:@"Unsaved Changes" detail:@"You have unsaved changes, would you like to save?" andButtons:@[@"Save", @"Continue", @"Cancel"]];
                alertView.delegate = (id <CCAlertViewDelegate>)self;
                [self.controls addChild:alertView z:100 tag:kAlertViewTag];
            } failure:^{
                CCAlertView *alertView = [[CCAlertView alloc] initWithMessage:@"Save Failed" detail:nil andButtons:@[@"Okay"]];
                alertView.delegate = (id <CCAlertViewDelegate>)self;
                [self.controls addChild:alertView z:100 tag:kAlertViewTag];
}];
```

I'm not exactly sure on what I am doing wrong, is it the block that is throwing it off? I use this line on code in other places and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Ah realized that I needed to add the view using

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{}];
```